# Confusion regarding conservation of momentum and conservation of energy

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, momentum, conservation-laws, mass-energy

When solving the problem under in the two different ways listed, i end up getting different answers.

> An electron is moving with $v_1=0.87c$ perpendicular to a positron moving with $v_2=0.98c$ in an intertial frame of reference. The particles annihilate, and two photons are produced, each with equal energy $E_f$.

a) Conservation of momentum: $\vec{p}_{0}=\vec{p}_x+\vec{p}_y=\vec{p}_1$

Electron: ${p}_x=\gamma_1 mv_1=\frac{mv_1}{\sqrt{1-(v_1/c)^2}}=\frac{mv_1}{\sqrt{1-0.87^2}}=\frac{9.11\cdot 10^{-31}\cdot 0.87\cdot 3.00\cdot 10^8}{\sqrt{1-0.87^2}}=4.822\cdot 10^{-22}kgm/s$

Positron: $p_y=\gamma_2 mv_2=\frac{mv_2}{\sqrt{1-(v_2/c)^2}}=\frac{mv_2}{\sqrt{1-0.98^2}}=\frac{9.11\cdot 10^{-31}\cdot 0.98\cdot 3.00\cdot 10^8}{\sqrt{1-0.98^2}}=1.346\cdot 10^{-21}kgm/s=13.46\cdot10^{-22}kgm/s$

Total momentum: $|\vec{p}_0|=p_0=\sqrt{p_x^2+p_y^2}=1.430\cdot 10^{-21}kgm/s$

Momentum conservation $p_0=p_1$ where $p_1=\frac{E_{total}}{c}$ yields: $p_0=p_1=\frac{E_t}{c}\Leftrightarrow E_t=p_0c$, $E_f=\frac{p_0c}{2}=\frac{1.430\cdot 10^{-21}\cdot 3.00\cdot 10^8}{2}=\underline{2.145\cdot 10^{-13}J}$ per photon

b) Conservation of energy: $E_1=2E_f$ where $E_1=\gamma_1 mc^2+\gamma_2 mc^2, E_f=E_{photon}$

$E_1=\gamma_1 mc^2+\gamma_2 mc^2=mc^2(\gamma_1+\gamma_2)=9.11\cdot 10^{-31}\cdot (3.0\cdot 10^8)^2\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-0.87^2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-0.98^2}}\right)=5.783\cdot 10^{-13}J$

Which gives $E_f=\frac{E_1}{2}=\underline{2.892\cdot 10^{-13}J}$ per photon.

This is whats confusing me. To my understanding, both conservation laws should apply in this process. So which of the two methods a) or b), if any, is correct?

Comment: Is there an issue assuming you can just add the momenta of the two photos together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Momentum is a vector quantity. In your first solution, you tacitly assumed that the photons came out parallel to each other, when you treated their momenta like scalars. This is in fact incompatible with energy conservation, giving the wrong answer.

Comment: I see. The assumption would’ve held true if and only if net momentum before annihilation equaled zero, and the resulting energy was evenly distributed between an even number of parallel photons? How would I go about solving this problem using the “conservation of momentum approach”?

Comment: @VBG Honestly, the conservation of energy method is so much simpler that I can't think of a reasonable way to do it using momentum that wouldn't basically use the energy result as an intermediate step. The reason energy is so much easier in this case is that they explicitly tell you something about the energy (namely that they are equal).

Comment: @VBG However, in a general problem, to use energy conservation you'd have to set up the two components of momentum separately. Let the photons have angles $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$, project their momenta, take the $x$ and $y$ components. You can see how this would be more complicated. Generally, you would not have enough information to solve for the $\theta_i$ without being given something extra, in this case that they have equal energies.